# Suggestions for a tools or any other method that allows extracting data from mongoDB and then move it to another environment of same product?

Tags: mongodb, automation, etl, data-migration, data-integration

I'm working on a website with different environments. The data management tool is MongoDB. Previously, I was running automation testing script on environment 1 and now I have to do that on environment 2. In order to do that, I have to have the same data on environment 1 in environment 2.

I'm looking for any suggestion on moving data from environment 1 to environment 2. Such as some ETL tools or any other methods that you think could work.

Thank you my friends.

Answer (score 0):

you can use cloneDatabase function like this on env2:

```
> use mydb
> db.dropDatabase();
> db.cloneDatabase("192.168.11.52")
```

change 192.168.11.52 to your env1's ip;